# Is there any way to make the Bottle servers less verbose?

Tags: python, bottle

Is there any option *on the Bottle side* that can keep servers like *WSGIRef* and *Paste* from outputting a line for every request received?

**NB:** I know there's a *quiet* option, but I don't want the entire appication to be silent, just the request log.

It gets very messy very quickly, especially considering that I'd like to print debug information now and then and it just gets lost in the chaos. Here's the output for a single page-load, and it'll probably get a lot bigger when my project grows a little:

```
Bottle server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:05:59] "GET /clients HTTP/1.1" 200 3129
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:05:59] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:05:59] "GET /static/js/jquery-1.7.2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:05:59] "GET /static/js/jquery.cookie.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:05:59] "GET /static/js/jquery.qtip.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:05:59] "GET /static/js/showdown.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:05:59] "GET /static/js/proj.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:05:59] "GET /static/css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:06:00] "GET /static/images/flag_gb.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:06:00] "GET /static/images/flag_no.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:06:00] "GET /static/images/icon_add.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
localhost - - [28/Jul/2012 04:06:00] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 742
```

Comment: If you used mod_wsgi instead, apache would split the access and error logs.

Comment: This is for development though - Apache is a bit hardcore. Additionally, Bottle's restarter wouldn't work

Comment: If no one has a real solution, you could just pipe the output to `grep -Ev '(GET|POST)'`

Comment: I'm on Windows, but thanks for the command anyway :-)

Comment: `grep` is available in cygwin if you need to resort to the hack.

Comment: @jordanm: `grep`, as well as a lot of other useful tools, is also available on Windows as part of [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this in the past.  For the different kind of servers you can overwrite the log handler to filter out logs you dont want.   I copied the code from Bottle and make my own ServerAdapter, Below is the code for a WSGI server.  Similiar to the quiet feature overriding the log_request function my own handler class and overriding the original log_request then filtering out the message based on the response code passed to the function.

i copied the log_request function from the built in BaseHTTPServer module and added the if statement.

then when you start bottle, pass it your customer serverAdapter

```
from bottle import route, run, template
import bottle

@route('/hello/:name')
def index(name='World'):
    print "Debug Print Statement"
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

class WSGIRefServer(bottle.ServerAdapter):
    def run(self, handler): # pragma: no cover
        from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server, WSGIRequestHandler

        class LogHandler(WSGIRequestHandler):
            def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'):
                """Log an accepted request.

                This is called by send_response().

                """
                if code not in  ["200", "304"]:
                    self.log_message('"%s" %s %s',
                                     self.requestline, str(code), str(size))

        self.options['handler_class'] = LogHandler
        srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, handler, **self.options)
        srv.serve_forever()


run(host='localhost', server=WSGIRefServer, port=8080)
```